# How to solve deprecation warning of JobBuilderFactory and StepBuilderFactory

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm using the following factories to set up my Spring Batch application:

```java
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
```

However, I'm getting the following deprecation warning:

```
The type JobBuilderFactory has been deprecated since version 5.0.0 and marked for removal
```

These are the bean declarations I'm using:

```java
@Bean
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory
        .get("csv-step")
        .<MSTabcNEUser, MSTabcNEUser>chunk(10)
        .reader(reader())
        .processor(processor())
        .writer(writer())
        .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
        .build();
}

@Bean
public Job runJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory
        .get("MSTabcNEUser")
        .flow(step1())
        .end()
        .build();
}
```

I'm also getting the following error:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'job': Error creating bean with name 'runJob' defined in class path resource [com/nissan/auraQuantics/config/SpringBatchConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'runJob' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'step1' defined in class path resource [com/nissan/auraQuantics/config/SpringBatchConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'step1' parameter 2: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter<com.nissan.auraQuantics.entity.MSTAuraQuanticNEUser>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2023-02-20T16:10:49.187+05:30  INFO 22644 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-02-20T16:10:49.199+05:30  INFO 22644 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-02-20T16:10:49.221+05:30  INFO 22644 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In stead of using `JobBuilderFactory` and `StepBuilderFactory`, you can use the `JobBuilder` and `StepBuilder` class:

```java
@Bean
public Step step1() {
    return new StepBuilder("csv-step", jobRepository)
        .<MSTabcNEUser, MSTabcNEUser>chunk(10, transactionManager)
        .reader(reader())
        .processor(processor())
        .writer(writer())
        .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
        .build();
    }

@Bean
public Job runJob() {
    return new JobBuilder("MSTabcNEUser", jobRepository)
        .start(step1())
        .build();
}
```

The big difference is that you need to pass a `JobRepository` to these builders and a `PlatformTransactionManager` to the `chunk()` method.
You can add these as fields to your configuration class.
For example:

```java
private JobRepository jobRepository;
private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
```

Also be aware that the `ItemWriter` interface has changed from supporting a collection of items to `Chunk<? extends T>`.
You may have to refactor some of your writers.
Check also the [Spring Batch 5.0 migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide).

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'writer' defined in class path resource [com/config/SpringBatchConfig.class]: A CrudRepository implementation is required

Comment: @Bean
    public RepositoryItemWriter<MSTabcUser> writer() {
        RepositoryItemWriter<MSTabcUser> writer = new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
       writer.setRepository(mSTabcUserRepository);
     writer.setMethodName("save");
        return writer;
    }

Comment: Is there a way to inject StepBuilder and JobBuilder in the configuration class instead of creating them with the new keyword? Creating them with the keyword "new" make unit testint untrivial.

Comment: @soung No, you have to create the `StepBuilder` and `JobBuilder` by yourself, so you'll always have to use the `new` keyword.  If this bothers you, you might be unit testing the wrong thing. I think it would be better if you create a separate question for your problem.